# How can i update an item in an array on firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a button that can edit an item within a documents array in firebase. Basically, the functionality I'm building is: you click an EDIT button, and it changes a

tag into an  tag where you would make your edit/update to the array item. Then you would click a DONE button and the update to the array would happen. For some reason, I can only find documentation on firebase for updating a document, and not an item inside the array. I've tried using arrayUnion but it only adds a new item to the array. I'm trying to update the info[0].tags in the screenshot below. Please let me know if I'm missing information to help make this work.

My issue seems to be I can't do: info[i]: arrayUnion({tags: tags}) so I'm not sure how to tell the updateDoc function which item in the info array I need to update.

Here's the code:

```
  const editCard = async (tags, i) => {
    const fieldRef = doc(db, "labels", activeLabels);
    await updateDoc(fieldRef, {
      info[i]: arrayUnion({ tags: tags }),
    });
    console.log(tags);
    getLabels();
    findLabel(activeLabels);
    toast.success("Tags Updated!");
  };


[![firebase document and array][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDJcc.png
```

Comment: There is no way to update an existing item in an array in Firestore. You will have to: read the document, update the array in your application code, and then write the entire array back to the database.

Comment: Apologies, I'm a self-taught programmer and am a bit confused by the best way to proceed. When you say "Update the array in your application code", isn't that what I'm currently trying to do? I guess my mistake here is I'm trying to update an existing array - and you're saying to delete the array and re-make it with the new changes? Can you possibly provide me with some example code? I'm not asking for a blatant answer but just something I can rework or expand on to get my desired result. If not, thank you for the advice either way.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-array-operations is this the correct documentation to follow @FrankvanPuffelen?

Comment: You're trying to update the item without reading the document (so step 2 without step 1) which isn't possible. I linked two questions that cover this in more detail, one with many more links to other questions about the same problem.